# What is the best place for tools like phpcpd, phpmd, php_codesniffer

Tags: composer-php, phpcodesniffer, phpmd

What is the best place for tools like phpcpd, phpmd, php_codesniffer to include them in composer `require-dev` section or install as `phar` archive somewhere in the system?

When they are included in require-dev often it is not possible to update for newer version because of some old components in the project. If installed as `phar`, it is harder to track versions of this tools and harder to check if these tools are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The best is composer!** [`require-dev`](https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/blob/master/composer.json#L58-L70) section, because that ensures **every uses has the same version**.

When I download you package, and you use e.g. PHPUnit phar 4.9 and I will have PHPUnit phar 6.0, it will probably fail. And we would have long conversation, where the bug is :).